# Adding leading zero with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

say I have a string like

```
'1 - hello.mp3'
'22 - hellox.mp3'
'223 - hellox.mp3'
'hellox.mp3'
```

I hope to output to be

```
'001 - hello.mp3'
'022 - hellox.mp3'
'223 - hellox.mp3'
'hellox.mp3'
```

that is if the starting is number, appending 0 to make it three digits.

Is there a way to achieve using regex in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, regexes can do that. Use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback function:

```
import re

def pad_number(match):
    number = int(match.group(1))
    return format(number, "03d")

fixed_text = re.sub(r"^(\d+)", pad_number, text)
```

The pattern I used, `^(\d+)` matches 1 or more digits (`\d` is a digit, `+` will match at least one time but will encompass all following digits), but only at the start of the string (`^` is the 'start of text' anchor here).

Then, for each matched pattern, the `pad_number()` function is called, and the string that that function returns is used to replace the matched pattern. Because the pattern uses a *capturing group* (everything between `(` and `)` is such a group) the function can access the matched digits by calling [`match.group(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group).

The function turns the digits into an integer, then uses the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) to turn that integer back into text, but this time as a 0-padded number 3 characters wide; that's what the `03` formatting instruction tells `format()` to produce.

Note that the pattern can match *more* digits, but limiting them doesn't make much sense unless there is a strict upper number you want to limit to (at which point you need to also add a restriction on the next character *not* being a digit). The `format(number, "03d")` instruction produces a number *at least* 3 digits wide but can handle longer values.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> samples = [
...     '1 - hello.mp3',
...     '22 - hellox.mp3',
...     '223 - hellox.mp3',
...     'hellox.mp3',
... ]
>>> def pad_number(match):
...     number = int(match.group(1))
...     return format(number, "03d")
...
>>> for sample in samples:
...     result = re.sub(r"^(\d+)", pad_number, sample)
...     print(f"{sample!r:20} -> {result!r:20}")
...
'1 - hello.mp3'      -> '001 - hello.mp3'
'22 - hellox.mp3'    -> '022 - hellox.mp3'
'223 - hellox.mp3'   -> '223 - hellox.mp3'
'hellox.mp3'         -> 'hellox.mp3'
```

Again, take into account that this method doesn't special case strings with 4 or more digits at the start; you simply get a longer sequence of digits:

```
>>> re.sub(r"^(\d+)", pad_number, "4281 - 4 digits")
'4281 - 4 digits'
>>> re.sub(r"^(\d+)", pad_number, "428117 - 6 digits")
'428117 - 6 digits'
```

This would happen even if we limited the `\d` pattern to only match up to 3 digits (e.g. with `\d{1,3}`).

If you wanted to make the padding width configurable, you can put everything in a nested function and use string formatting. You don't really *need*

```
import re

def pad_leading_number(text, width):
    def pad_number(match):
        number = int(match.group(1))
        return format(number, f"0{width}d")

    return re.sub(fr"^(\d+)", pad_number, text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> pad_leading_number("22 - hellox.mp3", 3)
'022 - hellox.mp3'
>>> pad_leading_number("22 - hellox.mp3", 7)
'0000022 - hellox.mp3'
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answering!

Comment: someone dv both - maybe a "no attempt on question, lets downvote all answers" dv ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks a lot! A side question: is it possible to put the 3 as a function parameter or variable to be input by the user?

Comment: @william007: yes, with string formatting you can generate regular expression patterns, and you'd want to use a closure to have the replacement function pick up the parameter for use in `format()` function.

Comment: @william007: so put everything in a function (including the `pad_number()` function, unaltered other than indentation), with `width` as a parameter, and change the `format()` call to `format(number, f"0{width}d")`.

Comment: @william007: I realised there is actually no point in setting an upper limit to the digit matching, so I changed that to just use `+`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Noted, great changes

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for regex - (see [Martijn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723200/7505395)) - but can do it with string manipulation as well:

```
data = [ '1 - hello.mp3', '22 - hellox.mp3', '223 - hellox.mp3', 'hellox.mp3' ]


def prefixZeroIfStartWithNumber(t):
    """Splits t at first space, if convertable to in, prefixes with three zeros
    and returns it together with remainder of t. Else returns t."""
    spl = t.split(" ",1)
    try:
        k = int(spl[0])
        return f"{k:03} {spl[1]}" # format with zeros, add remainder
    except (ValueError, IndexError): 
        return t

for text in data:
    print(prefixZeroIfStartWithNumber(text))
```

Output:

```
001 - hello.mp3
022 - hellox.mp3
223 - hellox.mp3
hellox.mp3
```

---

Alternate way - supposedly to be faster:

```
def prefixZeroIfStartWithNumber(t):
    number, _, remainder = t.partition(" ")
    try:
        k = int(number)
        return f"{k:03} {remainder}" # format with zeros, add remainder
    except (ValueError, IndexError): 
        return t
```

Using [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

Comment: someone on a wild dv spree - gotta love it.

Comment: Well, that at least gives some credence that they may be from someone that feels that we didn't aught to have answered this question, and not because we missed something in our answers.

Comment: Pro tip: when splitting just *once* on a fixed string, use `str.partition()`; it is faster for that usecase. E.g. `first, _, rest = t.partition(" ")`.

Answer (score 0):

@martijn Pieters gave you the *correct answer*, but you could also do the same simpler, run this regex twice:

```
regex = r"^(?=\d\d? )"
replacedby = "0"


^ asserts position at start of a line
Positive Lookahead (?=\d\d? )
\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
\d? matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) between zero and one times
Matches SPACE

I use the positive lookahead to match the lines starting with ## - but not including the ## - in the match, then I replace the start of the line with 0
```

Here I show you the same in javascript for simplicity :

```js
const regex = /^(?=\d\d? )/gm;
const str = `
1 - hello.mp3
22 - hellox.mp3
223 - hellox.mp3
hellox.mp3`;

const subst = `0`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst).replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

See the example online in this link and export it to python or other languages:

https://regex101.com/r/jVsY5v/1/